# MVC 4 with SignalR submit form and keep show notification

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have to do a simple validation that if I select some person on my `DropDownList` I need trigger a simple notification via `SignalR` to all users.

But the code doesn't work correctally because after that the user is redirected to another View, and then, the notification doesn't appear. It works just if I don't submit the form to another View.

I want that even if the form is submitted, I need to show my notification via SignalR when some person is selected on my `DropDownList`, can someone help me with this?

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Signal() {        
        var chat2 = $.connection.redirecionarTarefa;

        chat2.client.broadcastMessage = function (nome, mensagem) {            
            var htmlNotificacao =
                "<div id='toast-container' class='toast-bottom-right'>"
                + "     <div class='toast toast-info' style=''>"
                + "         <button class='toast-close-button'>×</button>"
                + "         <div class='toast-message'>Attention! Task redirect to " + mensagem + ".</div>"
                + "     </div>"
                + "</div>";

            $("body").append(htmlNotificacao);
        };

        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {   
                if ($("#ddlAtribuir :selected").text() != "Select")                 
                    chat2.server.send("Lucas", $("#ddlAtribuir :selected").text());
                }
        });
    }    
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Principal", "Home")) {                    
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputEmail3">Atribuir Para</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <select id="ddlAtribuir" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">Select</option>
                    <option value="1">John Doe</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Signal()" style="box-shadow: none;" value="Concluir" />
}
```

Comment: You should have the RPC handling code on the 2nd page as well, and the user might need to register to the Hub also.

Comment: @AD.Net I think this occurs because when I submit the form, the page is reloaded and then is loaded a new content in `body` so, I miss my notification.

Comment: Why don't you send the notification from the server (in your controller) instead of from the client (in your js)?

Comment: SignalR has the client layer and the server layer, I don't inderstand very well your solution @Daniel, do you have some sample ?

Comment: @AD.Net Thanks, I understand what you said now, and did works.

Comment: You can send the notification from your server when the form is submitted, no?